# Error in importing data from salesforce in exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

In my exacttarget when I'm importing data from salesforce report I'm getting "Casesensitive Salesforce Id" error.
I'm importing data from salesforce Campaign reports which contains Lead/Contact Id column.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue recently where I got the error **CaseSensitiveSalesforceID** when I tried to import into Exacttarget a Salesforce report built on a custom report type that included the contact id field from a lookup.

*The issue was that Exacttarget/Marketing Cloud doesn't just expect a contact id or lead id as the key it also expects the column name to be exactly **Contact ID** or **Lead ID**.*

The default value in my custom report type was **Primary Contact : Contact ID**. I changed this to **Contact ID** and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across an article I think relates to your error for the case sensitive salesforce ID.

Do you have ContactID or LeadID set as primarykey on the import? Then I think this article will give you some tips:

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000213103&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Use 18 characters Salesforce Id (eg. leadId or contactId) to update in Marketing Cloud