# CaseSensitiveSalesforceID when uploading data to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm importing some data into a data extension via Data Extensions, and most of the data has gone in without problems. However, it's highlighted about 100 rows as being unable to import due to 'CaseSensitiveSalesforceID'.

We aren't using Salesforce IDs in Marketing Cloud - we don't have the connector to Sales Cloud, and this data has not come from Salesforce. It's not even clear which field this refers to. What is causing this?

Comment: Sounds like a platform bug.  Is the import field named 'Contact ID' by chance?

Comment: I've seen this before, but only for accounts that have the Connector. Refer to [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136549/cannot-import-15-character-salesforce-ids-into-a-data-extension/154261#154261) for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug I believe you need to contact MC Support they will create an internal case on your behalf with developers.

Answer (score 0):

As per [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213103&language=en_US&type=1) in [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119437/error-in-importing-data-from-salesforce-in-exacttarget) , it is mentioned that Marketing cloud throws this error when a record is imported to a data extension having primary key and the record contains duplicate case sensitive primary keys.

Can you check your import record for the primary key column values.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is that when you  export SalesforceID's via the connector, it is converted to has to be converted to an 18 digit id. The reason for this is that the salesforce database is case sensitive. so AbC , aBB,ABC are all unique.

Enter marketing cloud, where the parts of the database that deal with these are case-insensitive.

In order to resolve this, Salesforce appends 3 digits all in caps.

To resolve this in the past, I have used an online coverter to convert t15 digits ids into 18. I would recommend these : [www.sf1518.click](http://www.sf1518.click)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is because your data might contain any value starting with 003 or something like that. Marketing Cloud consider this as a Contact Id of sales cloud record even if do not have any connection with sales cloud. Contact MC support and get this script of validation error removed for your account.